# One of the div tags not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a simple program but one of my div tags is not showing and I am unable to understand why

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascripts/Services.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascripts/MainScript.js"></script>   
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    UserId
                </th>
                <th>
                    Id
                </th>
                <th>
                    Title
                </th>
                <th>
                    Body
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in Posts">
                <td>
                    {{x.userId}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{x.id}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{x.title}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{x.body}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add Record"/>
    </div>
     <div id="create">
         <form name="post">
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>UserId</td>
                     <td><input id="userId" ng-model="userId" type="text" /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Id</td>
                     <td><input id="Id" ng-model="id" type="text" /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Title</td>
                     <td><input id="Title" ng-model="title" type="text" /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Body</td>
                     <td><input id="Body" ng-model="body" type="text" /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" ng-click="AddPost()">
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Js Code

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['EnukeService'])
        .controller('MyController', function ($scope, MyService) {
            $scope.Posts = {};
            GetAllPosts();

            function GetAllPosts() {
                debugger;
                var getPostsData = MyService.getdata();
                getPostsData.then(function (post) {
                    $scope.Posts = post.data;
                }, function () {
                    alert('Error in getting post records');
                });
            }

            $scope.AddPost = function () {
                var post = {
                    userid: $scope.userId,
                    id: $scope.id,
                    title: $scope.title,
                    body: $scope.body
                }


            var getpostData = newsLetterService.postData(post);
            getpostData.then(function (msg) {
                GetAllNewsLetters();
                alert(msg.data);                
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in adding post record');
            });
            };
            })
```

the last div tag containing the form is not showing on the page, Can you please let me know if I am missing something
Earlier 2nd div tag was also not showing but later it started to showup the button I am unable to understand this behaviour

Comment: post the related css as well, chances are there's a reason that id is not being shown.  probably related to a state change hitting the 'add' button.

Comment: unless your JS hides it, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: did you check your `js` code or `css` it may be `hide` or `dispaly none`

Comment: Since you have the javascript tag, I assume javascript is involved and you have not supplied that so it will be impossible to help you: [mcve]

Comment: I have added the javascript also, I didn't hide the tag

Comment: Well, now we discover you are using angular and that changes everything.

Comment: @Rob Can you tell me the possibilities of mistake I am making

Comment: I cannot. I won't use Angular and know nothing about it.

Comment: Can you add the CSS?

Comment: @nym I didn't use any css

Comment: if you are asking why your save input isn't showing up, it's because you can't put an `<input>` inside a `<tr>` element, it needs to be in a `<td>` element.  the `<input>` is in "voodoo mode".

Comment: I put this in a plunkr and see the form in the div. What I don't see is the input in the last tr, which isn't surprising because you need a td in a tr. In the future, I recommend creating a plunkr like this:
https://plnkr.co/edit/AJv8ii6MyrbExlUUeiav?p=preview

Comment: @nym I used the plunker code, It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @claies, the one part of the markup that was clearly wrong was nesting elements other than a td / th in a tr.

```
<tr>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" ng-click="AddPost()">
</tr>
```

**The only permitted child nodes (elements) of a TR are "Zero or more  or  elements, or a mix of them"**

--https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

When I put the code into plunker and ran "Beautify your code", the editor even stripped the input.btn entirely from the output.

Your code sample can be played with here- https://plnkr.co/edit/AJv8ii6MyrbExlUUeiav?p=preview